# Would you consider this a poor interface design?

Tags: design, design-patterns

How would you treat an interface where you cannot supply its dependencies before runtime ?

`IDelta` looks like this;

- `void Create();`
- `void Update();`
- `void Delete();`

Consider this constructor on a type - `DeltaCalculator` - which inherits from the `IDelta`.

```
public DeltaCalculator(IEnumerable..., IEnumerable...){}
```

The constructor takes instances of something which is calculated on runtime - hence I cannot wire `DeltaCalculator` up in the dependency container, and then I find myself new'ing it up where I need it.

The interfaces is locked due to the missing possibility to give each of the 3 contract methods any parameters - no parameters can be supplied to either method.

The only other possible strategy I see is, and if I do not wish to new instances up, is to add a new method to the contract along the lines of;

- `SetData(IEnumerable....,IEnumerable...);`
- `void Create();`
- `void Update();`
- `void Delete();`

But that is really a leaky approach I think. But then I can wire the type on my dependency container and escape the new'ing.

What would you do?

Comment: Dependency injection (DI) is an idea/pattern that's separate from DI containers (the pattern doesn't imply a container - see pure DI). You don't have to use containers *at all* to make use of DI. A container is just a library used for convenience. Things that are at a smaller level of granularity, or are more of an internal detail of a component, don't have to be provided by a container. Sometimes, `new` is OK. Now, often you can inject a factory, as explained by Euphoric; this lets you encapsulate the `new`, allowing you to inject a different dependency by providing a different factory.

Comment: Let me explain the mechanics of it a bit more: if a component's constructor takes an IDelta as a dependency, change its signature to take an IDeltaFactory instead, or alternatively a lambda that takes the two enumerables and returns an IDelta. Then in the DI container provide a factory (or a lambda), and encapsulate the call to `new` within it (e.g. `(e1, e2) => new DeltaCalculator(e1, e2)`). At runtime, when the enumerables are ready, pass them to the factory.

Comment: P.S. [pure DI link](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) - couldn't fit it in the original comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is why abstract factory pattern exists.

```
interface IDeltaFactory
{
    public IDelta Create(IEnumerable....,IEnumerable...)
}

interface IDelta
{
    void Create();
    void Update();
    void Delete();
}
```

This way, you can inject the factory as dependency and pass the `IDelta` with the right data to whenever it is needed, without that code having knowledge about how the delta was created.